# Rails validation: style two invalid fields but only list one error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following custom validation:

```
def city_presence
  if city_id.blank? && city_out_state.blank?
    errors.add([:city_id, :city_out_state], "A City must be present")
    throw(:abort)
  end
end
```

It errors out, but what it is trying to do is this:

- See if both `city_id` and `city_out_state` are both blank

  - If so, then add BOTH of those fields to the errors hash in order to provide *invalid styling* to both fields on the form, but only display **one** error bullet point message.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working solution:

```
def city_presence
  if city_id.blank? && city_out_state.blank?
    errors.add(:city_id, "A City must be present")
    errors.add(:city_out_state, "")
  end
end
```

And here is the errors partial.  The key is that an error's message does not generate an `li` if the error's message is not `present?`:

```
<% if object && object.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>

    <p><%= pluralize(object.errors.size, "error") %> prohibited this record from being saved</p>
    <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
    <ul>
      <% object.errors.each do |attr, message| %>
        <% if message.present?  %>
          <li>
            <%= message %>
          </li>
        <% end  %>
      <% end  %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```